# Увеличение знаков после запятой

Tags: c++

Доброго всем времени суток! Хотел бы поделиться проблемой, и может кто-то подскажет что-нибудь стоящее. У меня есть число А, определяемое выражением

> `long double A = B/C;`

и мне нужно, чтобы точность этого числа была не менее 15 знаков после запятой! Как это делается в С++? Как можно повысить точность числа?! Может быть в настройках пакета? (стоит Visual Studio 2005)

Comment: double и без long имеет (помнит) 15 знаков после запятой

Comment: Я тоже так думал! Но вот конкретно в моей задачи при использовании в моем методе вот такого числа А (рассчитанного по этому выражению) получается один результат (ответ)! А когда явно присваиваю числу А рассчитанное из маткада это отношение(с 15-ю знаками после запятой) получаю другой ответ (как раз который и должен получаться)! Таким образом я пришел к выводу, что эта погрешность (разница между двумя ответами) получается из-за округления числа А в моей программе!?

Comment: В и С какого типа и с каким количеством знаков после запятой определены?

Comment: Тип такой же long double, и по 8 знаков после запятой!

Comment: Тогда, откуда же в А найдется 15 (пятнадцать!) верных знаков?

Comment: Да, наверное вы правы... То есть, чтобы получить точность порядка 15 чисел, нужно чтобы как минимум B имело порядка 15 знаков после запятой?

Comment: только что не поленился проверил:

1 / 3 = 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125

(gcc версия 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4) (GCC))

Comment: Все так и есть! Просто нужно было увеличить точность числа В, и все заработало! Извиняюсь конечно за некорректно поставленный вопрос, но благодарю за помощь и за подсказку!!! :) Плюсанул вам к рейтингу, и постараюсь в другой раз более детально прорабатывать подобные проблемы!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В числах с плавающей запятой точность зависит от размера числа. Например, если это число порядка миллиона и имеет тип float, то оно может хранить только один знак после запятой.

Для независящей от величины числа точности лучше использовать числа с фиксированной запятой. Например, чтобы хранить большие суммы денег с точностью до копеек, лучше использовать не float, хранящий рубли, а unsigned int, хранящий число копеек. Для очень больших чисел и очень большой точности можно использовать __int64, или long long.

Если и этого не хватит, то можно поискать отдельную библиотеку с классом типа BigInteger. Они позволяют выбрать любую точность, но платить за это придётся значительным снижением производительности работы с этими числами.

Comment: На delphi для этого есть тип Currency. В общем случае фиксированная точка тоже не обязана стоять после младшего разряда. Язык может поддерживать денежный тип с фиксированной запятой, но при этом дробный. Например, два младших разряда могут хранить сотые, а точка стоять после целых. Тогда целые можно считать рублями, долларами, гривнами... Чем угодно, хоть галактическими кредами из Elite, а два младших разряда будут копейками, центами...

Comment: Если Вы храните целое количество сотых в обычном инте, то при умножении в младшем разряде будут десятитысячные, то есть точка убежит на те же два разряда, а дробь с фиксированной запятой учтёт это в реализации оператора. Хотя, деньги на деньги умножать смысла мало.

Answer (score 0):

Опять вопрос про float подлиннее? [gmp](http://gmplib.org), [mpfr](http://www.mpfr.org)

Comment: Ну да. А Вам надо про чары покороче?